# How to use a unique identifier in ibeacon?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

I am developing an iOS app in which I need to read something `unique` from my `ibeacon` which I can change and customize that unique value.

I bought [this](http://radioland-china.com/English/Product/6035982553.html) beacon and there is no way to change it's `UUID`, `major` and `minor` values.

`CoreLocation` just gives `UUID`, `major` and `minor` values. If I use `CoreBluetooth` I don't know how can I recognize my beacons from other bluetooth devices and also I don't know if there is a `unique` value.

Is there any possible way that I can read a `unique` value from this beacon which I can change?

Answer (score 1):

`iBeacon` protocol only supports `UUID`, `major` and `minor` values.
This is by design and you can't change that.

If you do then you're not using `iBeacon` anymore.

I'm not familiar with that particular hardware but the specs state that you **can** change `UUID`, `major` and `minor` values.

This is the only information you'll ever get from a beacon and you can't connect to it, this is also by design.

To translate `UUID`, `major` and or `minor` to a unique value means that you need to bake this into the app itself and not rely on the beacon to return this.

One way of doing this is to create a `Dictionary` that translates `UUIDs` to `unique`.

Answer (score 1):

`UUID`, `major` and `minor` is your unique value. The way it suppose to work: you should define `UUID` for your whole set of beacons and use this inside app, then just use `major` and `minor` to recognize each beacon.

Each beacon also have it's own unique id, but it's usually not changeable and you can't see this unless you make a direct connection to the beacon.

Comment: Getting this unique id depends on what kind of beacons do you use. You need to use SDK in order to get more data from beacon. 
Also from what I see right now, in beacons settings panel for Kontakt.io, when you use Eddystone it's possible to set INSTANCE ID. Maybe switching to Eddystone will solve your issue.